# warning: 'offsetof' within non-standard-layout type is conditionally-supported

Tags: c++, zephyr-rtos

I'm trying to use the `CONTAINER_OF` macro in a C++ application for Zephyr RTOS. My struct looks like this:

```
struct auto_update_config {
    std::function<int()> update_value_func;
    k_work_delayable update_work;
    uint32_t num_failures;
    k_timeout_t update_period;
};
```

When I try to use `CONTAINER_OF`:

```
static void auto_update_work_handler(struct k_work* work) {
    struct k_work_delayable* dwork = k_work_delayable_from_work(work);
    struct auto_update_config* ctx =
        CONTAINER_OF(dwork, struct auto_update_config, update_work);
    int err = ctx->update_value_func();
    ...
}
```

The compiler gives a warning:

> warning: 'offsetof' within non-standard-layout type 'auto_update_config' is conditionally-supported [-Winvalid-offsetof]

> 451 |                 CONTAINER_OF(dwork, struct auto_update_config, update_work);

I imagine the `std::function` is what's causing this warning, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I need the struct to contain a field for a function with this signature, and I can't use a C-style definition `int (*update_value_func)()` because the value is the result of a `std::bind`.

Is there a way to achieve this same effect without getting this warning (other than just disabling the warning flag)?

Comment: Formally `CONTAINER_OF` macros have in almost all cases undefined behavior according to the C++ standard anyway and the warning is just telling you that `offsetof` is not guaranteed to work with non-standard-layout types on all compilers. By using `CONTAINER_OF` your goal can't be 100% standard-conforming portable code anyway, so there shouldn't be any problem with disabling the warning. Given that it didn't fail to compile your compiler does seem to support it.

Comment: Make sure you test this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this same effect without getting this warning (other than just disabling the warning flag)?

You could separate your `auto_update_config` structure into two parts. One that contains the `update_work` member that you apply `CONTAINER_OF` to, and the other one with the rest of the members, that derives from the first one. Then you can use a `static_cast` to convert from the base class to the derived class to have access to `update_value_func` and other members.

```
struct auto_update_config_base {
    k_work_delayable update_work;
};

struct auto_update_config :
    public auto_update_config_base {
    std::function<int()> update_value_func;
    uint32_t num_failures;
    k_timeout_t update_period;
};

static void auto_update_work_handler(struct k_work* work) {
    struct k_work_delayable* dwork = k_work_delayable_from_work(work);
    struct auto_update_config_base* ctx =
        CONTAINER_OF(dwork, struct auto_update_config_base, update_work);
    int err = static_cast< struct auto_update_config* >(ctx)->update_value_func();
    ...
}
```

The trick here is that `auto_update_config_base` remains a standard-layout class and hence supports `offsetof`. The `static_cast` supports non-standard-layout classes and will work correctly as long as the pointed object is always of the `auto_update_config` class.